# Metadata and GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, metadata, specification

My agency currently maintains and distributes shapefiles with FGDC XML metadata.

We have now converted a lot of shapes to GeoJSON but are concerned that if our developers forget where they got the data, then they will not know who to blame when their node apps break.

Is there a GeoJSON metadata specification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there isn't a GeoJSON metadata specification.

Definitely do not put metadata in the properties object as @R.K. suggests.

I would suggest, as @albert does, using some JSON-LD. You could add Dublin Core metadata to a feature collection like so:

```
{ "@context": {
    "description": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/description",
    ... },
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "description": "My features",
  ... }
```

(See also https://github.com/geojson/geojson-ld/blob/master/contexts/geojson-dcterms.jsonld)

If you like to keep using FGDC metadata, you could add a link to a metadata document to your JSON.

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "fgdc": "http://example.com/metadata.xml",
  ... }
```

Just make sure that you explain to others (by using JSON-LD maybe) what the sense of this "fgdc" item is.

Comment: the see-also-link is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no metadata specification for GeoJSON (At least it isn't on the current spec). You can try putting the metadata in properties. Or add a reference linking to metadata there.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not aware of one for geojson, so this fails your question, however over at http://github.com/datasets we've been using datapackages.json, a module documented by okfn
http://data.okfn.org/doc/data-package
you could also check out json-ld spec by the w3c